# create metafield on shopify

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I want to create metafield every time when my shopify customer subscribe to product on my shopify store so i got following code to create metafield but don’t know how it would work on liquid theme ? Can any one guide me where i need to write following code to make it functional ?

```
‘POST’, ‘/admin/products/1328/metafields.json’, array(“metafield” => 
array(‘namespace’=>’inventory’, ‘key’=>’warehouse’, ‘value’=>"some text here",   ‘value_type’=>’string’)));
```

How can i make above code in liquid templating pages to create a metafield using shopify api ?

Comment: And i found another example and tried

product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(148362461) product.add_metafield(ShopifyAPI::Metafield.new({ :description => 'Developer of the Site', :namespace => 'chargify', :key => 'customer', :value => 'Metlo', :value_type => 'string' }))

It also didn't work, i need to know how can i create / update / delete a metafield on customers account page on shopify ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a metafield in liquid. If you want to create metafields, you must use admin API / graphQL API to do so.

Liquid only allows you to "print" existing data to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Pure liquid "interacted" by visitor of your store, won't be allowed to do anything with the Shopify API. You need to have an Oauth open session in order to post / read your store data.

Comment: i want to interact it with every customer to post / view data specially metafields using shopify so i want to know when ever my customer goes to memberships page and subscribe to any plan through chargify and come back to our site after successful subscription and once subscribed, i want to create metafield on shopify site so i could check in future that logged in customer have subscribed or not.

Comment: can you tell me how can i use Oauth open session to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

For your example you would reference the meta field in this way.

{{ product.metafields.inventory.warehouse }}

that would then show

"some text here"

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to make a controller and method that will receive an AJAX request and make a call to the Shopify API.

Create click event on the product subscription button.
Click event will look like this:

```
let url = 'https://your_host.com/your_contoller/your_method?shop=your_shop_domain';
let postData = { product_id: "your_product_id" };
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: url,
  data: postData,
  dataType: 'json',
  complete: (res) => {
      console.log(res); // response from your_method
  }
});
```

In the controller method, you must use the Shopify client as phpish/shopify or any other.
With the client using api_key, access_token of your app or private app, you can make this kind of request:

```
POST /admin/api/2020-10/products/PRODUCT_ID/metafields.json
{
  "metafield": {
    "namespace": "inventory",
    "key": "warehouse",
    "value": 25,
    "value_type": "integer"
  }
}
```

After you should get back the result.

But if you want to create metafields on request from your customer, it's better to wrap controller method in a queue and use the queues, because if you don't use the queues there's a chance to fall within the limit of Shopify REST API.

After create a metafield, you can get value from liquid with code from Richard.

Answer (score 0):

Liquid is read-only as some of the answers mentioned.

However, I built a app called [FieldsRaven](https://apps.shopify.com/fieldsraven) to handel this kind of use cases – it's a niche app for Shopify theme developers so you shouldn't use the app unless you know what you're doing.

The `resource_type` (customer, page, producct, etc...), `namespace`, `key` and `value_type` are defined on the app side when you create a Raven, [developer docs](https://docs.fieldsraven.app/quick-start) will explain the steps.

All you need to do is to trigger the `ravenSubmitCustomerUpdate` function on a spesific event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ravenSubmitCustomerUpdate = (value) => {
    const ravenObj = {%- render 'raven-mac-gen', resource_id: customer.id, raven_id: 'TBD' -%};
    const valueObj = { value: value };
    const response = Raven.send(ravenObj, valueObj);
    response.then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log('', res.json)
      } else {
        console.error('', res)
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
  }

  {% if customer %}
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      ravenSubmitCustomerUpdate("some text here");
    })
  {% endif %}
</script>
```